Lifting non magnetic and non flat objects with a lifting electromagnet
My aim is to create a robotic arm with a lifting solenoid electromagnet as the end effector to lift round objects like balls. The objects would weigh about a kilo or over 2 pounds.
I was thinking something like a claw with some soft padding on top of the electromagnet such that when the electromagnet is activated the claw would close and grip whatever object is inside. Will it work? What challenges would I face?
What are the ways I can lift a non magnetic non flat object with a lifting solenoid electromagnet?
An example of such an electromagnet is linked below
https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicscomp.com%2Fimage%2Fcache%2Fcatalog%2Fdc-24v-p40-20-30kg-lifting-solenoid-electromagnet-800x800.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=0a0358050a11c7762ca38efad6011c193b5cfff6f9ad285fbc6cde7e380b957d&ipo=images
